# Hide pagination if records fits in one page in datatables angular

Tags: angular, datatable

I am using angular 11, and I have used [angular datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) to show some records in table. Now I want to disable/hide pagination if the records are less than or equal to 25.(25 is the default pageLength I am using). I saw couple of solutions but they are using jQuery. Please see my code snippet as below -

```
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 25,
  columnDefs:[{
    targets: 3,
    type: 'date'
  },{
    targets: 4,
    type: 'date'
  },{
    targets: 5,
    type: 'date'
  },],
  info: false,
  stateSave: true,
  dom: '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"ilp><"clear">',
  language: {
    search: "_INPUT_",
    searchPlaceholder: "Search Clients",
    lengthMenu: '_MENU_',
},
};
```

Please see below a service to fetch client records -

```
this.clientService.getClientsData().subscribe((result: any) => {
  this.clients = result.data.filter((item: any) => item.is_Active);
  this.originalClients = result.data; //active + inactive
  this.dtTrigger.next();
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.utilityService.isLoading.next(false); //stop loader after 1 sec
  }, 1000)
}, err => console.log(err));
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can add a CSS class that hides the footer on condition `result.length < dtOptions.pageLength`

Comment: If you can make a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy) demo, I can help with the solution.